# How to start a daemon using Spring injection from a webapp

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I need to start a daemon when I deploy a war.  The daemon itself uses objects that should be injected with Spring.  I did the following:

In web.xml

```
...
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>example.AppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

AppListener.java

```
public class AppListener implements ServletContextListener {
...
  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
      log.info("======================= Begin context init =======================");
      try {
        // final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml");
        final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml");
      //final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("//Users/.../WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml");

      final SessionServiceDaemon sessionServiceDaemon = context.getBean(SessionServiceDaemon.class);
      sessionServiceDaemon.start();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      log.error("Was not able to start daemon",e);
    }
}
```

SessionServiceDaemon.java

```
@Service
@Singleton
public class SessionServiceDaemon {

  private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionServiceDaemon.class);

  private final SessionServiceHandler handler;

  @Inject
  public SessionServiceDaemon(final SessionServiceHandler handler) {
    log.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ SessionServiceDaemon injected");
    this.handler = handler;
  }
```

My springapp-servlet.xml simply has the packages required for the injection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...

  <context:component-scan base-package="example" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

In the startup logs, I see as expected:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ SessionServiceDaemon injected
```

followed by

```
======================= Begin context init =======================
```

Problem is: I then get an exception that the file does not exist no matter which path I use to point to springapp-servlet.xml:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I tried different relative paths and even the absolute path without success.  I even edited the code above and added just above my attempt to load the context the following:

```
  try {
    log.info(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml")));
  } catch (final Exception e) {
    log.error("Unable to find file",e);
  }
```

and that printed the content of springapp-servlet.xml just fine.

My 2 questions:

- How can I get a "class path resource  [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist" when I am able to display the file content using the exact same path from the same method?
- Do I have the correct approach anyway for starting a Daemon that has dependencies that are injected?

PS: I use Tomcat.

Comment: On the classpath resource piece... `src/main/webapp` only exists in your maven project. Use a zip utility and you'd see that `WEB-INF` is in the root of your WAR, and `src/main/webapp` is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Yes. Using new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml"); was actually my first attempt, but I got the same error.  That's when I started using alternate relative and absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting two different spring application contexts.  The first, the built-in [ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html), is likely picking up your springapp-servlet.xml configuration from default locations.  (You didn't say if you are specifying a contextConfigLocation.)

In your custom listener, you then construct a new application context using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext with an explicit path. Of the three lines you've shown, only the one with ""WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml" looks like a possible candidate for classpath resolution, although it really depends on how you've configured and startup your Tomcat instance. (i.e. What is the classpath from Tomcat's point-of-view?)

Regardless, there are better ways to get the Spring application context in to a servlet/listener.  A direct approach is to use the ContextLoaderListener as you have done, but then in your custom servlet/listener, make use of Spring's [WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#getWebApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29).

Spring has direct support for servlets as well, including configuration via annotations, the [HttpServletBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean.html) class, or even using [FrameworkServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html) directly.

Comment: Edited my Q to show how I set contextConfigLocation. I hadn't realized I was starting a second app context when I just wanted to access the existing one, thanks. I am still unclear what your suggestion is.  That I keep my existing code and simply change the way I set context by using WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext?  However, that method expects a servlet context and I don't have one available from within my AppListener, do I?

Comment: Yes, you can keep code as is and use that method.  You can get the ServletContext from the ServletContextEvent parameter given in the contextInitialized method.  However, if for some reason you find that using a listener does not work for you, then you could always use a servlet instead, using the "load-on-startup" setting in web.xml to make sure your servlet gets started.

Comment: Many thanks. Silly me had not realized the context listener could return the context.  My code works now.  For the future, I am still not 100% sure whether this approach I took is the standard/best approach to follow for kicking in a daemon (or running anything at startup for that matter) when that daemon relies on Spring dependencies.  Do people typically do what I did here?

Comment: Spring provides some arguably more elegant methods via the HttpServletBean and/or using the newer Servlet 3.0 WebServlet annotations, however, your approach is sane for starting a custom daemon. I personally prefer servlets over listeners for this simply because I often need  HTTP 'status' API to monitor my daemon.

Comment: If you did not need anything servlet related, you could also simply construct your daemon from within the Spring context as a standalone bean (and it could start itself with it's own thread).  While your approach of using the listener/servlet to bootstrap is valid with Tomcat, some other app servers (especially strict J2EE compliant servers) might take issue with you starting unmanaged threads off of a listener/servlet.  Yet another approach would be to use Spring's scheduling services to run your daemon.  But the short answer is yes...your approach is valid.